# Можно ли декомпозировать объект (класс) в PHP?

Tags: php

Например, как в JS:

```
const = {READABLE, CREATABLE, DELETABLE} = WP_REST_Server;
```

Чтобы так не расписывать:

```
[WP_REST_Server::READABLE, WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE, WP_REST_Server::DELETABLE]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно. Но делать этого, скорее всего, не надо. PHP поддерживает ООП, а в этой парадигме значение свойств вашего объекта не должно торчать наружу. Но если речь о ассоциативном массиве или [DTO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO)'шке, то можно сделать так:

```
<?php

$obj = (object) ['foo' => 'aaa', 'bar' => 'bbb'];
['foo' => $foo, 'bar' => $bar] = get_object_vars($obj);
var_dump($foo, $bar);
```

Подробнее об этом можно прочитать в  [документации](https://www.php.net/list).